# Отсортировать данные PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Как написать запрос, чтобы получить 3 `name` с `type=0` еще 3 с `type=1` и 3 с `type=2` в итоге 9 `name`. У меня выводится только с `type=0`. Ругается на `UNION ALL`.

```
Select forum_thread.name, forum_thread.updatedat, forum_thread.threadtype
From forum_thread, business
Where business.id = 1 AND forum_thread.threadtype=0
Order by forum_thread.threadtype, forum_thread.updatedat desc limit 3
UNION ALL
Select forum_thread.name, forum_thread.updatedat, forum_thread.threadtype
From forum_thread, business
Where business.id = 1 AND forum_thread.threadtype=1
Order by forum_thread.threadtype, forum_thread.updatedat desc limit 3
UNION ALL
Select forum_thread.name, forum_thread.updatedat, forum_thread.threadtype
From forum_thread, business
Where business.id = 1 AND forum_thread.threadtype=2
Order by forum_thread.threadtype, forum_thread.updatedat desc limit 3
```

Comment: `order by` в `union [all]` пишется один раз в конце запроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
  from (
   Select forum_thread.name, forum_thread.updatedat, forum_thread.threadtype,
          row_number() over(patition by forum_thread.threadtype Order by forum_thread.threadtype, forum_thread.updatedat desc) RN
     From forum_thread, business
    Where business.id = 1 AND forum_thread.threadtype in(0,1,2)
  ) X
 where RN<=3
 Order by threadtype, updatedat desc
```

Если по каким то причинам это работает медленнее, чем ваш вариант с тремя union, то просто заключите подзапросы в скобки `(select ... limit 3) UNION ALL (select ... limit 3)`